# tar.gz created in windows cannot be unpacked propertly under linux - ArchiverFactory / org.rauschig.jarchivelib.Archiver

Tags: java, linux, tar

I'm using in my tool (Java)
ArchiverFactory  / org.rauschig.jarchivelib.Archiver 
https://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/examples.html
to create tar.gz archive under windows which have to be uncompressed under linux, but there is something wrong with filetree.

for example, I want compress folder test/ which contains
test/a.txt
test/b.txt

```
Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.TAR,CompressionType.GZIP);
archiver.create("archive", new File(path/to/dir/test), new File(output/path));
```

So I have archive.tar.gz, which contains (on windows) one directory test, and 2 files in this directory (a.txt and b.txt):

```
/test/a.txt
/test/b.txt
```

BUT after uncompressing the same archive on linux (tar -xvf archive.tar.gz) I have one empty directory (test) and 2 files which have name of directory&file with slash "/":

```
/test/
/test\a.txt
/test\b.txt
```

I'm using "/" in all my paths under windows, also tried "\ \" but without success. Unpacking on linux looks like that:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/temp$ tar -xvf archive.tar.gz 
test/
test\\a.txt
test\\b.txt
```

What's wrong with this slashes/backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was library issue... I was using 0.7.1, but on updated recently 0.8.0 this issue is fixed ;) So, always use latest versions!